# how to print the contents of a remote .php file

Tags: php

my code:

```
$fp = fopen('http://192.168.127.128/test.php', 'rb');
while(!feof($fp)){
    echo fgets($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

and the test.php is:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

I just want to print the contents of test.php, but it prints the result of test.php actually. What should I do to print the contents of test.php?

Comment: Open it in such a way that the server doesn't know it's a PHP file. Renaming it to another extension is one option. But of course you can only do that if you have ftp or telnet access or one of those file manager GUIs, and then you could just download it. If you don't have access to the source at all, you could ask the owner to send it to you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents / code of a remote PHP file, you will typically need to SFTP it off the server or retrieve it in another way where it isn't executed. If you run the web server and don't want to execute PHP files at all, you can configure the web server to render the PHP code as a text file.

When you access a PHP file over a URL like `http://192.168.127.128/test.php`, the PHP file will typically be interpreted by the web server and you will only receive the output result.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using cURL.

```
        $url = 'http://192.168.127.128/test.php';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $return = curl_exec($ch); 

        echo $return;
```